# Using of the "from" preposition in the context

Tags: grammar

Here is a definition of the word "blush":

> blush - develop a pink tinge in the face from embarrassment or shame.

If I understand right "from" is a preposition that signifies the reason of the process and we can substitute it with "because of" as an example.

Well, if it so, can I say the next... Would it be right?

> I bought a new phone from I lost my old.
>
> I've stayed at home from the rain
>
> I have good marks at school from my passionating of studying

It's so unnatural, Is it right?

Comment: So you found out that you can _not_ always substitute _because of_ with _from_, which is correct. Note that of your three sentences, the first and the third sound unnatural with _because of_ as well. The first one works with _because_ (without _of_) and the third one just doesn't work. I'm not sure _passionating_ is even a word. Maybe you mean _passion_.

Answer (score 1):

"From" indicates the *source*.  When used in talking about motion, it is the originating direction of the motion:  I walked from the bus stop, I come from France.  When used with its more abstract meaning, it is the originating state or event from which the thing you're discussing comes.  An abstract source is similar to a cause, but there are many other types of causes that can't be thought of as metaphorically similar to sources of motion.  In order to be thought of as a source, the cause has to be physically linked to the thing it causes. Being embarrassed is the trigger or origin of blushing, but losing your phone isn't the origin of buying a new one, the rain is not the origin of your staying home and your passion for studying is not the origin of your grades.

Comment: *From X* - X is a source, not a reason.  If X has a subject and verb, then the word you have to use is a conjunction, typically *because*.